# Cannot save configurable products anymore!

Tags: ce-1.9.1.0

I got a serious issue. I used to be able to create configurable products but I cannot anymore. I create lets say 2 simple products using the `BagSizes` attribute and then create the configurable product using that `BagSizes` attribute and associate with the simple products I created. When I click Save, it then goes back to the product list without saving. No error whatsoever.

Any ever had this problem?

Using Magento 1.9.1 (Was before on Magento 1.7.1)
Also, creating normal products work. Could it be a database problem?

Answer (score 1):

Check your memory limit in php.  In `index.php` add the following line near the top:

```
ini_set("memory_limit","2048M");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can find do it

1 .- Check Store View (if products has this view)

2 .- Check Stock Attribute (if product has stock)

3 .- Check Set    Attributes in Store View (if attributes apply to product)

4 .- Check Attribute Apply to type product
    ( Configurable , Simple ...  )

5 .- Enable show errors in Index.php ( check anny error if it apply to save product )

6 .- Check var/log/system.log ( Show current status magento errors)

7 .- Check Session and Cache 8 .-
    After changes in Catalog Product ReIndex All Index

List item

Answer (score 1):

Go to your magento database, and table **catalog_category_product** . The one that holds the products and see if the "auto increment" is checked.

Answer (score 1):

You can check your exception log in var/log/exception.log and also try to check Ajax response of click on save button which can show error.

I hope it will help you.